# How to progress the progressbar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, progressdialog

I want the progressbar to increase when it matches a string. Like if I click yes, the yes bar will increase. But for some reason I am unable to make it progress.

Code:

```
public class result extends VoteActivity{

        private ProgressBar mProgress;
     private int mProgressStatus = 0;

     private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.alert);
if(choice=="Yes")
{   
         mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.p1);

         // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                     ++mProgressStatus;


                     // Update the progress bar
                     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                             mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                         }
                     });

             }
         }).start();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot compare strings with `==`. You need to use `equals()`:

```
if(choice.equals("Yes"))
```

Comment: @Floem Thanks for that, but after that the emulator force close, when I click on Yes

Comment: @Samrat: Where do you define `choice`? Can you post your onClickListener?

Comment: @Floem I am defining choice in another class/Activity and importing that class here and using that String variable. I want when my string returns Yes, the progressbar of yes should progress.

Comment: It seems you have some problems with `choice`. You have to make sure you assign a value to it.

Comment: @Floem Ya, the error is choice is having problem, how can i access a glbal variable in class2 from class1, even extending class1 in class2 is not working

Comment: You cannot access `choice` of `VoteActivity` from your `result` class. You need to pass the value when you create your new `Intent` or you make the `choice` field `static` and then you could access it as `VoteActivity.choice`. Otherwise your `choice` gets lost.

Comment: I'd like to suggest using `"yes".equals(choice)` instead. If choice is null you wont get an exception, instead it'll just be false.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to do `a.equals("Yes")` and instead did a comparison of references?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Floem you may want to look at using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
This will come in handy if before or after your background process you will want to update the UI thread.

Another thing that does exactly what you have and avoids all the call to post is [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). While you may not be showing your counting numbers, your can certainly use it as a time out.